# Not able fetch the right output because of the parsing error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, parsing, node-modules

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import ProductList from "./Components/ProductList";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const productList = [
    {
      price: 9999,
      name: "IPhone 10S Max",
      quantity: 0,
    },
    {
      price: 999,
      name: "Redmi Note 10S Max",
      quantity: 0,
    },
  ];

  let [productList , setProductList] = useState(productList);

  const incrementQuantity = (index) => {
    let newProductList = [...productList];
    newProductList[index].quantity++;
    setProductList(newProductList);
  };

  const decrementQuantity = (index) => {
    let newProductList = [...productList];
    newProductList[index].quantity > 0
      ? newProductList[index].quantity--
      : (newProductList[index].quantity = 0);
    setProductList(newProductList);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main className="container mt-5">
        <ProductList
          productList={productList}
          incrementQuantity={incrementQuantity}
          decrementQuantity={decrementQuantity}
        />
      </main>

      {/*<Footer/>*/}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;



**Line 21:7:  Parsing error: Identifier 'productList' has already been declared. (21:7)**
```

Not able fetch the right output because of the parsing error.

Comment: oh my god... was your attempt not to get any answers by writing in all CAPS and copy-pasting the same sentence over and over again? Please do not EVER do that again, anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your state name of the value is the same like the object name:

```
//try to name it smth like initialProductList and pass it to useState(initalProductList)
const productList = [ 
    {
      price: 9999,
      name: "IPhone 10S Max",
      quantity: 0,
    },
    {
      price: 999,
      name: "Redmi Note 10S Max",
      quantity: 0,
    },
  ];

  let [productList , setProductList] = useState(productList);
```

Also,
`useState()` shuld be defind with `const` like so:

```
const [productList , setProductList] = useState(productList);
```